# Define Number of lists according with Number into Widget flutter

Tags: flutter

What I Have are number of orders received that has be shown into a tab into a widget in flutter according with this code:

```
class ShipmentTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShipmentTabState createState() => _ShipmentTabState();
}

class _ShipmentTabState extends State<ShipmentTab> {
  **final shipmentNumber = "16";**

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Card(
            color: Color(0xfffeaf0d),
            child: Container(
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.local_shipping,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13),
          child: Text(
            shipmentNumber,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

as you can see variable is " shipmentNumber " that show "16"
below I have listview.builder and I need to add itemCount and this count has to be refered to the tab above "16"
this is the code of the list:

```
Container(
          height: 400,
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, int) {
              return Card(
                color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
                elevation: 15,
                child: Container(
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Card(
                        color: Color(0xfffeaf0d),
                        child: Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.local_shipping,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 25,
                            )),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Ref № $int',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Mario Rossi',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Color(0xfffeaf0d),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Consegnato',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightGreenAccent),
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.share,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView.builder` has `itemCount` parameter. I notice shipmentNumber is in String so you can parse it to `int`. Also you need to remove the `Container` `height` wrapping your `ListView`

```
ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: int.parse(shipmentNumber),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          /** build your Item here **/
         return BuiltItem();
        },
    )
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the answer. Suppose I need to retrieve this number of item to be show in list but this number has to be retrieve into another widget, is shipmentNumber is also into another widget how I can retrieve this shipmentNumber from another widget and show into listbuilder?

Comment: You can try implement State management to Listen to a specic value using ChangeNotifier and Provider Package



https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple